# TransactionScope across AppDomains and processes

Tags: .net, database, ado.net, transactionscope, system.transactions

Is it real to use System.Transactions (primarily TransactionScope) across different AppDomains and processes?

[DependentTransaction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.dependenttransaction.aspx) works only inside one AppDomain.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it works.  We are flowing transactions via WCF, calling out of process transactional COM+ components, and manually passing transactions from a .NET 2.0 asmx web service to a WCF service.

Now that is not to say that the setup is not finicky.  I think most of the issues were around getting MSDTC set up properly on all the servers.

**UPDATE**

We don't use `DependentClone`.  We are passing the transaction as a byte array using `GetTransactionFromTransmitterPropagationToken`.  Very similar to the second example of [Propagating a Transaction Across AppDomains](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/sasha/archive/2010/04/30/propagating-a-transaction-across-appdomains.aspx).

As an example:

Client:

```
public void CallOutOfProcessAndPassTransaction
{
    Client client = new Client();

    client.DoSomethingTransactional(
        System.Transactions.TransactionInterop.GetTransmitterPropagationToken(
            System.Transactions.Transaction.Current)
    );
}
```

Service:

```
public void DoSomethingTransactional(byte[] tx)
{
    using (TransactionScope ts = new TransactionScope(
               TransactionInterop.GetTransactionFromTransmitterPropagationToken(tx)))
    {
        // Do Something

        // vote to commit the transaction if the caller also agrees
        ts.Complete();
    }
}
```

Comment: Could please tell more about the process of passing transaction to another AppDomain? Do you create clone by calling currentTransaction.DependentClone and pass it or just pass current transaction?

Comment: And what about committing such a transaction? I guess I can commit it only from initial AppDomain?

Comment: @ldsa: when you pass a Transaction across an appdomain you will be dealing with a distributed transaction. To commit the transaction all participants will have to vote to commit. e.g. appdomain1 and appdomain2 will both have to commit.

Answer (score 0):

I found problems with this style of solution.  In my case I was doing work in the parent and multiple children.  To get it to work I had to use TransactionScope only in the parent. My own question/answer are at [Using transactions across processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13574245/using-transactions-across-processes/13594119) .